# Azure Data Factory DataFlow Source CSV File Header Keep Changing

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I am trying load the CSV file from source blob storage and option selected for first row as a header but while doing multiple time debug trigger, the header keep changing, so that i could not able to insert the data to target SQL DB.

kindly suggest and how do we handle this scenario. i am expecting static header needs to configure from source or else existing column i would have to rename into adf side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Source settings "Allow Schema drift" needs to be ticked.
[image]

Allow Schema Drift should be turned-on in the sink as well.

[image]